# Can I make Rehsharper run a custom command before running any unit tests instead of the build

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, batch-file, resharper

The build in my team is a custom bat file, and not default visual studio build. If I want to build before running a unit test from resharper, I have run the bat file manually and then run unit test in resharper. The resharper setting has been set to "Never Build" so that it doesn't attempt to build it as well.

Can I make resharper also run the custom bat file for building instead of the default build ?

Answer (score 1):

No, there are no settings for this in ReSharper. Could you add a pre-build step in the Visual Studio project that runs your .bat file?

Comment: I do not want visual studio to also build the solution. Adding a pre build step will already build the required binaries.